# How does classoffset work in listings?

Tags: listings

Can someone please explain, how I can modify the following example, so that each dialect or language, can be colored differently? I have difficulty to understand what is the `classoffset` concept in `listings`. Read the manual a few times but I am still battling to grasp the concepts. How do languages relate to this? How does the styling array type styling relates to keywords? Why when I add another language `[5.3]Lua` does the coloring go awry?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\section{lststyles tests}
% Define a new language
\ExplSyntaxOn
\lstdefinelanguage{LaTeXiii}
  { alsoletter={_,:},
    morekeywords=[1]{cs_set_nopar:Npn,luadirect},
    moretexcs   =[2]{clist_new:N},
    morekeywords=[3]{\seq_new:N,\seq_set:Nn}
  }%
\ExplSyntaxOff
\lstloadlanguages{[AlLaTeX]TeX, [LaTeX]TeX,[primitive]TeX,LateXiii}




\lstdefinestyle{simple}{%
  keywordstyle={\ttfamily\color{brown}},% [0]?
  keywordstyle=[1]{\ttfamily\color{blue}},%
 texcsstyle=[2]{\ttfamily\color{red}},%
  texcsstyle=[5]{\ttfamily\color{purple}},%
  keywordstyle=[3]{\ttfamily\color{orange}},%
  keywordstyle=[4]{\ttfamily\color{green}},%
  basicstyle={\ttfamily\color{black}},%
}


\lstnewenvironment{myenv}[1][]
{
  \lstset{
  language=[AlLaTeX]TeX,%
  alsolanguage=[LaTeX]TeX,
  alsolanguage=[primitive]TeX,
  alsolanguage=[plain]TeX,
  alsolanguage=LaTeXiii,%
  %alsolanguage={[5.3]Lua}, ***** <- How do I get this right?
  }
  \lstset{style=simple,#1} %allow options for new listing
}
{}



\begin{myenv}
\begin{luacode}
local a=12
\end{luacode}
\cs_set_nopar:Npn\mycommand
\def\test{}
\advance \setcounter
\clist_new:N \l_my_clist
\seq_set:Nn \l__my_seq
% TeX primitives
\addcontentsline
\advancepageno
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
Output after I load `[5.3]Lua` as suggested in the comments. It gets better. To clarify the question better. How can I combine languages and have them display their own colors? Do I have to specify `classoffsets`? How do these work?

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question (what is your current output, what do you want the output to be, which settings do you want to add, how/with what syntax/options/commands do you think you should add them, what happens if you do that). However, for adding Lua it seems changing the order works, i.e., `\lstset{language={[5.3]Lua}, alsolanguage=[AlLaTeX]TeX,` etc. So probably `alsoletter` gets overwritten if a later language also sets that, or something along those lines.

Comment: @Marijn Current output without Lua is ok. Trying to find out what is the correct workflow for combining languages. My approach, defined a new lang for l3. Defined a style and then an environment. lsitings manual talks about classes as well. I think I had to add it somewhere, did, but keppt messing up.

Comment: @Marijn Sorry misplet your handle above. It does get better when I put Lua above